# sql file cant validate multiple stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So some background I am setting up a cloudformation stack from our CICD pipeline. This stack sets up our entire database. We have migration files that get triggered, great! So far this is working well, my db builds all my views and tables, except it does not build my procedures and I've been banging my head against my desk trying to figure out why. I've looked at a ton of documentation, I really don't understand why what I have is not working when it looks EXACTLY as it should from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) and several other similar sites I found.

Now I believe I know the cause of the issue, I am currently using SQLPro which generates a SQL dump of my DB, which is used in my cicd process and gets triggered. I've ran the dump file in SQLPro and it works fine, but does not work when just trying to execute from an sql file, not in SQLpro, but in our cicd pipeline.

I feel like this must be a really simple problem, I've tried every flavor I can think of trying to format it correctly and I really have no idea why it's not working. I've been using an SQL validator online, and if I put ONE stored procedure it says the syntax is fine, but when I have more than 1 it's not.

Here's 2 procedures as an example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cropsByGrowerIdProc(IN userID Text)
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT
    g.growerID AS growerID,
    g.firstName AS firstName,
    g.lastName AS lastName,
    z.zoneID AS zoneID,
    g.farmName AS farmName,
    g.email AS email,
    g.phoneNumber AS phoneNumber,
    u.userID AS userID,
    g.source AS source,
    json_object('cropID',c.cropID,'plantedAcreage',c.acres) AS crops
  FROM GrowerDICT g
  inner join UserGrowerTransaction u on (u.growerID = g.growerID AND u.userID = userID)
  left join CropTransaction c on (c.growerID = g.growerID)
  inner join ZoneTransaction z on(z.growerID = g.growerID)
  where (u.userID = userID AND g.isActive IS TRUE);
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE cropsByGrowerIdProc_OLD(IN userID Text)
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT
    g.growerID AS growerID,
    g.firstName AS firstName,
    g.lastName AS lastName,
    z.zoneID AS zoneID,
    g.farmName AS farmName,
    g.email AS email,
    g.phoneNumber AS phoneNumber,
    u.userID AS userID,
    g.source AS source,
    json_object('cropID',c.cropID,'plantedAcreage',c.acres) AS crops
  FROM GrowerDICT g
  inner join UserGrowerTransaction u on (u.growerID = g.growerID)
  left join CropTransaction c on (c.growerID = g.growerID)
  inner join ZoneTransaction z on(z.growerID = g.growerID)
  where (u.userID = userID AND g.isActive IS TRUE AND c.isActive IS TRUE);
END;
```

Yes, I've tried DELIMITER's in any spot I can it just always says `you have an error in your sql syntax near CREATE PROCEDURE cropsByGrowerIdProc_OLD`

So again, this is just what I have now, I have tried many other things like delimiters, removing the begin/end, removing the drop procedure if exists (couldnt get that to work either, and errored out on the first create stored procedure line instead of the second without the drop procedure calls)

Comment: I don't know sql pro and gpogle also but you can export the functions and procedure with myswldump and run the sql file

Comment: can you share the sql pro dump?

Comment: @James Sure, is there a good way to do that? It's a pretty big dump lol, I don't think posting in the OP would be beneficial for anyone, it would make this page very long. However UPDATE: I was able to get this working by manually splitting up each procedure into its own file, so I know my syntax is fine, it just doesn't like when there's more than one procedure in the sql file. Even though tables/views work fine in 1 file.

Comment: *I was able to get this working by manually splitting up each procedure into its own file* so share the dump file only with 2 sp. If that is what you have shared above( in the beginning of post) then it won't work for even single sp since the delimiter were missing.